# How to access objects from event listener in javafx

Tags: javafx, event-listener

I have an object Contract and it contains Summary and Observable List of another object ContractDetails inside it.

Now, I am using ContractDetails to populate in tableview from Contract object.

I have a save button, which on clicking needs to save Contract along with ContractDetails. I am able to access ContractDetails since they are in tableview.

How do I access Contract properties in eventlistener of save button.

The related code is given below

```
    public class Contract {

    private String tradeDate;
    private String contractNote;
    .....
    .....
    private String brokerId;  
    private ObservableList<ContractDetails> contractdetails = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    public Contract() {
        }
    public Contract(String tradeDate, String contractNote, ....., String brokerId,ObservableList<ContractDetails> contractdetails) {

            this.tradeDate = tradeDate;
            this.contractNote = contractNote;
            ....
            ....
            this.contractdetails=contractdetails;
            }    

    public String getTradeDate() {
        return tradeDate;
    }

    public void setTradeDate(String tradeDate) {
        this.tradeDate = tradeDate;
     }

    public String getContractNote() {
        return contractNote;
    }

    public void setContractNote(String contractNote) {
        this.contractNote = contractNote;
     }

    ....
    ....

    public ObservableList<ContractDetails> getContractdetails() {
        return contractdetails;
    }

    public void setContractdetails(ObservableList<ContractDetails> contractdetails) {
        this.contractdetails = contractdetails;
    }

    }


    public class ContractDetails  {

    private String orderNo;
    private String contractType;
    private String symbol;
    private String buysell;
    private Integer quantity;
    private Double buysellprice;
    private Double netcontractValue;

       public ContractDetails() {
    }


      public ContractDetails(String orderNo, String contractType, String symbol, String buysell, Integer quantity, Double buysellprice, Double netcontractValue) {

        this.orderNo = orderNo;
        this.symbol = symbol;
        this.buysell = buysell;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.buysellprice = buysellprice;
        this.netcontractValue = netcontractValue;
    }
    public String getOrderNo() {
        return orderNo;
    }
    public void setOrderNo(String orderNo) {
        this.orderNo = orderNo;
    }

    ....
    ....

    public Double getNetcontractValue() {
        return netcontractValue;
    }
    public void setNetcontractValue(Double netcontractValue) {
        this.netcontractValue = netcontractValue;
    }
        }

In the controller
================== 
    public class ContractViewController implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    private TableView<ContractDetails> tblcontractfx;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<ContractDetails, String> contractTypefx;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<ContractDetails, String> symbolfx;
    ....
    ....
    @FXML
    private Button savefx;
    @FXML
    private TextField txtclientcodefx;
    @FXML
    private TextField txttradedtfx;


    private void fetchContracts(TableView tableView, Contract contract)

    {           txttradedtfx.setText(contract.getTradeDate());
                txtclientcodefx.setText(contract.getClientCode());

                 symbolfx.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<ContractDetails, String>("symbol"));
        contractTypefx.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<ContractDetails, String>("contractType"));

    tableView.setItems((ObservableList) contract.getContractdetails());

    @FXML
    private void saveClicked(ActionEvent event) {  DBConnection DBcon = new DBConnection();
    //Now I am getting the contract details from tableview tblcontractfx
    ObservableList<ContractDetails> contractdetails = tblcontractfx.getItems();
    //How do I get the summary values from contract. I am able to get those which are in text fields like txttradedtfx and txtclientcodefx.However contractNote which I am not using, I still need to retrieve it to populate into database.

      String clientCode=txtclientcodefx.getText();
```

Thanks

Comment: I've read that 3 times now and have no idea how you set that up and what your problem is. Can you please be more specific, maybe with some code? Usually you'd have an fxml with a controller which contains a contract and a tableview with the contract details. And a single save button. So you could access the contract in the event listener of the save button. Where's the problem?

Comment: Are you making these classes yourself?  Just put a reference in  ContractDetails to the parent Contract.  If you're using some provided classes from an API like IB's? then that's not how they work.

Comment: I have added the code. Hope it helps. I am making the classes myself. Since the ContractDetails are the child of Contract, I am seeing what will be the elegant way of getting Contract. Can you explain "Just put a reference in ContractDetails to the parent Contract". Pardon me, my OO concepts and java skills arent that great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just store the contract in a local variable.

```
Contract contract;
private void fetchContracts(TableView tableView, Contract contract)
{  
this.contract = contract;
...
}


private void saveClicked(ActionEvent event) {  
// here you have full access to the contract variable
String contractNote = contract.getContractNote();
}
```

As an alternative, if you insist on combining it all in a single table, you could put the Contract into the table via [setUserData](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#setUserData%28java.lang.Object%29) and retrieve it via [getUserData](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#getUserData%28%29).

By the way, I still don't get your code. Why is there a `tableView` parameter when you have full access to `TableView<ContractDetails> tblcontractfx`

Comment: Thank You Roland, that solves the problem. I am passing the name of the tableView which needs to be populated with the contract. Yes, in a way it is redundant, since tableview will be same. I will look at using setUserData.Right now, am inserting data during regular sql insert sqlstring="INSERT INTO TB_CONTRACTS(CONTRACT_KEY,TRADE_DATE,CONTRACT_NOTE ...... QUANTITY,BUYSELLPRICE,NETCONTRACT_VALUE,CLI‌​ENT_CODE) " + "VALUES(sq_contractkey.nextval+",'"+txtcontractfx.getText()+"','"+ ..... +contractdetails.get(i).getTradeNo()+"','" +contractdetails.get(i).getContractType()+"','"+ ...)